# How to create a CompletableFuture that uses cached values?

Tags: java, completable-future

I am familiar with using Guava's `Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration()` and `CacheBuilder` to cache lazily-load values.

I am having a hard time figuring out how to do the same for asynchronously-loaded values (using [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)).

Specifically, I want a mechanism that will return a `CompletableFuture` that will return a cached value if available; otherwise, calculate and cache the value.

I'm afraid that if I use `Supplier<CompletableFuture<Integer>> cache = Suppliers.memoize()` then the supplier will cache the `CompletableFuture` but consumers will re-run the pipeline every time.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick test dispelled my fears:

```
public final class Testcase
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        Supplier<CompletableFuture<Integer>> cache = Suppliers.memoize(() ->
        {
            return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
            {
                return random.nextInt();
            });
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            System.out.println(cache.get().get());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1171697378
1171697378
1171697378
1171697378
1171697378
1171697378
1171697378
1171697378
1171697378
1171697378
```

Thinking about it now, I realize that the `Supplier` will return the same `CompletableFuture` instance every time, and once a `CompletableFuture` completes it is guaranteed to return the same value every time. So we're safe.